# Create (class object) variable from string: Matlab

Tags: matlab, class, eval, cell-array

Say there is a cell array

```
A = {'objA', 'objB', 'objC'}
```

I want to have its members as instances of `MyClass` (see below) in Matlab. I couldn't get `genvarname` or `eval` to work for this.

Essentially I want loop through the array of names, `A`, and create a `MyClass` object for each member. This should result in the objects `objA`, `objB` and `objC`.

```
classdef MyClass
    properties
       something
       name
    end    
    methods
        function object = MyClass(name)
             object.name  = name;
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: Let's forget cell array, imagine I need a string like  `'a'` to become an object of `MyClass`, like as if I had `a = MyClass('TEST')`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define an instance of your [user defined class](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/user-defined-classes.html) `objA` using

```
objA = MyClass('objA')
>> objA = MyClass with properties:
>>        something: []
>>             name: 'objA'
```

So to create this from a string, use `eval`

```
ObjectName = 'objA';
% We want     objA = MyClass('objA')
% Equivalent: eval('objA = MyClass(''objA'')')
% To use the actual name from the variable instead of hard-coding, this becomes:
eval([ObjectName, '= MyClass(''', ObjectName, ''')'])
```

**Note** you must include quotes around the `ObjectName` variable when passing it into `MyClass` so that it is passed as a string. To include quotes within a string, you must "escape" them using another quote. This is why we get `'''` inside the `eval` statement.

To do this on an array, we can use a simple loop

```
A = {'objA', 'objB', 'objC'};
for ii = 1:numel(A)
   eval([A{ii}, '= MyClass(''', A{ii}, ''')']) 
end
```

---

However, see the MATLAB documentation for [Alternatives to the `eval` function](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/string-evaluation.html), because it's really not best practise to do this anyway. **You're far better off not naming the variables like this**. Store them, for example, in a cell array instead where you know the name for later access.

```
Objects = cell(1,3);
for ii = 1:numel(A)
    Objects{ii} = MyClass(A{ii});
end
```

You can see this code is much cleaner, easier to debug, and your objects are all stored neatly in a cell array of `MyClass` objects.

Comment: You are right, last suggestion paragraph works very good, nevertheless the third paragraph returns what exactly I meant.
Thank you!

Comment: Glad I could help and that you had a look at my alternate suggestion :)

Comment: It was a great help. I intended to use the exact name of some nodes that are read from a csv file as name of the objects and proceed so, but now I'm convinced to use your suggestion, because `eval` is not recommended and personally I had some issue with it.

Comment: You can always loop through the objects in the cell array later if needed, and check the `.name` property of your objects to find the one you want, could set this up as a simple function to return the index... but thats getting ahead of ourselves! Happy coding :)